# Given a geometric lane, how can I tell a car a path follow?

Tags: python, math, geometry, simulation

I'm trying to make a car follow a lane. I know all the points of the lane, as for now the lane is represented as a polygon, bounded by two sets of line segments. Given the the two boundaries, I want to find another set of line segments that a car would ride, like a railroad, such that it is always between the two boundary segments. The amount of lines in each boundary segment may not always be the same, the segments are not "parallel".

Diagram (this is a rather simple one, but I believe it conveys the message):

[image: Representation of what I want]

I've thought about the following, but I don't see them working, or at least not efficiently:

1. Splitting it up into quadrilaterals, or quadrilaterals and triangles,
2. Start with a line with length of ten, then rotate it until its end point is an equal distance away from both boundary sides and repeat and
3. For each output segment, average the slopes of both boundary sides.

I thought of a few more, but not worth mentioning.

Thank you for your help, please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: You tagged both python and java for your question. You should narrow it down to the programming language you actually want to work with.

Comment: That's interesting, but possibly might count as too 'asking for an opinion' for StackOverflow, unless there's one single clear answer. I guess you want this path to be as simple as possible i.e with as few turns but meeting some distance from the edges constraints? It feels like you could use some graph simplification algorithms with the right constraints e.g. the convex hull type algorithms that simplify complex lines.

Comment: Is the road witdth constant? Because if it is, drawing perpendiculars from points of one lane and taking midpoints of their line segments formed by their intersections with other lane should suffice.

Comment: The road width is not constant, I don't need it to be perfect, an approximate solution will work, as long as the output never exits the actual lane, and the path is somewhat efficient it will do.

Comment: You appear to be asking for an algorithm to find the [topological skeleton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton). Solutions to this problem are too broad for SO, but there is plenty of literature available.

Comment: Thank you Andy Turner, this looks exactly what i need, i will be sure to research this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following idea is inspired by [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW). It is an extension of Shreyas Pimpalgaonkar's idea in the comments:

The overall idea is to match points on one side of the street to points on the other side. E.g., distribute 100 points along both sides and try to draw lines between them. The criterion that we are going to use to match points is proximity. So, the total length of the connecting lines should be as small as possible. Once we have these lines, we can calculate their midpoints and connect them. This will also give you a smoother line, depending on how many points you start with.

Here are some details: Distributing the points is not that hard. You can either put points every x units. Or you could distribute a constant number of points on the segments. In the end, it does not matter too much how the points are distributed. Though, uniform distributions will give you better results.

The central point is the DTW variant. The essential data for this algorithm is a matching matrix that tells you how costly it is to match one point to another. For this, you can use the Euclidean distance of the two points. Once you have this matrix (it does not need to be a full matrix; the entries near the diagonal are usually enough; see locality constraint in the Wikipedia article), you just solve the warping problem with a dynamic program.

And finally, you connect to mid-points. That's it.

I should add that this is not necessarily guaranteed to keep the path inside the lane. However, it will break only with very weird road constellations. If you want to be on the safe side, you can adapt the cost matrix, such that the algorithm will not match points where the connecting line crosses the lane border.

Here are some examples. If you need smoother paths, you can change the point you choose on the connecting lines (instead of the midpoint). You could e.g. optimize the interpolation parameter with respect to the Laplacian of the generated line. This will give you a linear system of equations that lets you control the path's smoothness. However, it is not easy to guarantee that the path stays inside the lane anymore.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you have designed some code part then put in your question.Either only analyzing can make you many option it can be done via java /python both.

I am just showing you simple example which rather elaborate the path/lane follower used in maps.

```
private void CarMove(final Marker marker, final LatLng beginLatLng, final LatLng endLatLng, final long duration) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        // set car bearing for current part of path
        float angleDeg = (float)(180 * getAngle(beginLatLng, endLatLng) / Math.PI);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angleDeg);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(mMarkerIcon, 0, 0, mMarkerIcon.getWidth(), mMarkerIcon.getHeight(), matrix, true)));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // calculate phase of animation
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                // calculate new position for marker
                double lat = (endLatLng.latitude - beginLatLng.latitude) * t + beginLatLng.latitude;
                double lngDelta = endLatLng.longitude - beginLatLng.longitude;

                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * t + beginLatLng.longitude;

                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                // if not end of line segment of path 
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // call next marker position
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    // call turn animation
                    nextTurnAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to downvote this. Neither does it answer the question (it is a simple linear interpolation between two points; on top of that, on a sphere), nor is the code well explained or self-contained.